# Which ubuntu I should install?

Tags: software-recommendation

My hardware is:

- Celeron 2.80Gh
- 1 gb RAM
- 250 GB HDD

Though which Ubuntu version should I install in order to get a maximum fast performance from my PC, as when it (PC) was new?

Please, suggest me the version which will not freeze my computer.
Tried to install Linux mint, Ubuntu, but they're freezing or slowing my PC down.

Comment: The lightest desktop is [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) which should be really fast for you.

Comment: [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) is the lightest desktop but [Xubuntu](http://xubuntu.org/) may also be fine. Try them both from a live CD/DVD or USB and install the one you prefer.